# How to view GPX files, created by OSMTracker on desktop?

Tags: windows, gis

I want application, which can view GPX files, generated by OSMTracker application for Android. These files are accompanied with photos and audio records, which also should be shown.

P.S. Application should run on Windows, payment option doesn't matter.

Comment: On what desktop (OS) should this run? Must it be free, or are paid apps OK (which limit then)? What other features are required (e.g. map loading, and what kind of maps)? How are those files "accompanying" the GPX, i.e. how are they linked together?

Comment: The only required features are ones listed. Can be both free and paid. Limit is trillion of dollars. I don't know how files are linked to GPX, application should know this.

Comment: Bad luck then, I'm afraid: [GPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) IMHO doesn't hold information on "related files". A track point holds the coordinates (lat/lon), elevation (ele) and time (time) only. Relations can be made based on e.g. [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) tags in photos (by location info, if available, or creation time which is always available). Audio records could only be related by the files' time stamps. So you must somehow provide information on which files should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Viking](https://sourceforge.net/projects/viking/) to view and edit GPX files. You can use it both ways:

1) View generated GPX tracks or

2) Make GPX tracks and upload to your Android device

If additional data, e.g. audio and photo files, can be processed with Viking is beyond my knowledge. Just give it a try, it's free and open source. Hope, that helps

Comment: Here is what Viking showed when I opened GPX file: https://i.imgur.com/UdYUzGO.jpg     Found no any way to see something comprehended

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that Viking seems not yet to be working for you. I used to use it quite frequently in the past and it always worked fine, that is, displayed GPX files properly and allowed to edit them. Haven't used it for a couple of months, though. Use(d) it with Ubuntu Linux. As I'm not affiliated with the Viking team, I've got no idea how to get it working for you. However, if your Android app generates valid GPX files, I'm sure it should work for you, too.